# How to access API Response through button click

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress-rest-api

I need to access a Public Quote JSON API and display the content in my HTML page, I had little understanding of JQuery Ajax method. But my code is not able to pull the data into HTML. Please Explain the bug with my Code

```
$(".btn-primary").on("click",function(){
    $.ajax({
       type:"GET",
       url:"http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?
      filter[orderby]=rand",
       success:function(data){
        var post = data.shift(); 
        $("#quote").html(post.content);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Are there any errors to be seen in the console using developer mode on the browser?  Also could you show the HTML code as well?

Comment: Can you post your HTML? At least where you have the #quote and the button. I cannot see any errors in your code. Just tested it locally and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $(".btn-primary").on("click",function(){ 
        $.ajax({ 
            type:"GET", 
            url:"https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1", 
            success:function(data){ 
                $("#quote").append(data[0].content)
            },
            cache: false
        }); 
    });
}
```

Your ajax url will need to start wi "https" if you are running this from a secure site, otherwise, "http" will work.

Also, you need the "cache: false" part, otherwise it will keep displaying the same quote.